# xCode - beginBackgrounTaskWithExpirationHandler without limit (10 mins)

Tags: iphone, xcode, multitasking, ios-4.2

For my stopWatch project, i want to run the timer, when application goes to background (like "stopwatch" inside iPhone clock). I have tried 'beginBackgrounTaskWithExpirationHandler', but it will only execute the task up to 10 minutes. 
How can i do this without this limit. can any one help me how to solve this ....

Thanks for your quick reply..
Here is my code:

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)countDown{
    count = count - 1;

    //until 30 minutes i need to play an animation here... 

        if(count == 0)
        {
           //close timer...
        [myTimer invalidate];
        myTimer = nil;

           //update counter again
             [self updateCounter];
        }
}

//update counter function...

- (void)updateCounter{

    //setting count value
    count = 1800;

    //count-down fun
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

This is what i am looking to execute even in the background.... help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't (extend the background time of your app)
2. Use a [local notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you only need the time, simply adjust your clock when you application becomes active again.

If you need to be active at a certain time, use `scheduleAlarmForDate:`, see [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW31).

Comment: `scheduleAlarmForDate` is not a framework method. You should at least provide a link to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..
ViewController.m: 

- (void)countDown{
 count = count - 1;
 
 //until 30 minutes i need to play an animation here... 
}

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
              target:self
            selector:@selector(countDown)
            userInfo:nil
             repeats:YES];

Comment: @shebi: You will have the same problem. Use local notifications, or even better, use it *only* for the action at end of the countdown, and adjust you counter when the application becomes active (`applicationDidBecomeActive:`).